# Speed: GetAsyncKeyState() slow down dramtically if Taskmgr active

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I use heavily `GetAsyncKeyState()` to test some visual and speed aspects in the code.
What I see by hasard, GetAsyncKesState slow downs by factor about 100 if Taskmgr.exe is active and in  foreground.

To see this effect I have written a Hello world programm which check if a key is pressed in an endless loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <chrono>

using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
using std::chrono::duration;


#define IS_PRESSED( vk ) ( GetAsyncKeyState( vk ) & 0x8000 )    // Observation: Slow Down dramatically if Taskmgr.exe is active 
#define IS_ACTIVE( vk ) ((GetKeyState(vk) & 0x0001) != 0)


int main()
{
   std::cout << "Hello World!\n";

   auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

   int i = 0;
   while (!IS_PRESSED(VK_ESCAPE))       // Observation:  slow down ~100x if Taskmgr is active
// while (!IS_ACTIVE(VK_ESCAPE))        // ok, no time side effect
  {
     i++;
     if (i % 100000 == 0)
     {
        // Print speed
        auto t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
        duration<double, std::milli> ms_ElaspedTime = t2 - t1;  /* Getting number of milliseconds as a double. */
        std::cout << "Speed: " << ms_ElaspedTime.count() << " ms / 100'000 loops" << std::endl;
        t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
     }
   }
}
```

The Result is:

Speed:    0.445 ms / 100'000 Loops
Speed: 140.577 ms / 100'000 Loops   !!  (TaskMgr.exe Active)

Does someone have an explanation for this issue?

Comment: how did you compile the code? Btw `high_resolution_clock` is not recommended to be used, use `steady_clock` instead

Comment: Do note that 4.45 *nanoseconds* per call is rather fast.  TaskMgr.exe throws up considerable complications since it runs elevated, the security boundary that needs to prevent other processes from spying on its user input is untrivial.

Comment: @HansPassant Good explanation, but the similiar function `GetKeyState` has not this problem. I do not get it.

Comment: Despite their similar names, `GetKeyState` and `GetAsyncKeyState` perform entirely different operations. `GetKeyState` merely needs to do a table lookup in thread-local storage, no crossing threads, no thread synchronization, no transition into kernel mode. I'm pretty sure the latter has to do all of these.

Comment: Your problem is not reproduced in win11, what is your test environment?